# Simulating input change in functional component with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I've been having some issues when testing this component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import styles from './Join.module.scss';

const Join = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [room, setRoom] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === 'name') {
      setName(e.target.value);
    } else if (e.target.name === 'room') {
      setRoom(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className={styles.main}>
      <h1 className={styles.main__title}>Join</h1>
      <form className={styles.form}>
        <label className={styles.form__label}>Name</label>
        <input
          className={styles.form__input}
          name="name"
          type="text"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label className={styles.form__label}>Room</label>
        <input
          className={styles.form__input}
          name="room"
          type="text"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </form>
      <Router>
        <Link
          onClick={(e) => (!name || !room ? e.preventDefault() : null)}
          to={`/chat?name=${name}&room=${room}`}
        >
          <button className="btn btn--submit" type="submit">
            Sign In
          </button>
        </Link>
      </Router>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Join;
```

I want to simulate a change in the input `name="name"` but the test keeps failing since the result is always `""` instead of `foo`.

Can anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong? I've been searching for a solution with no luck.

Here's the test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import Join from '../Join';

describe('<Join />', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Join />);
  });

  test('1- renders without errors and matches h1', () => {
    const title = wrapper.find('h1');

    expect(title.text()).toBe('Join');
  });

  test('2- name input', () => {
    const name = wrapper.find('[name="name"]');
    console.log(name.debug());

    name.simulate('change', {
      target: { value: 'foo' },
    });

    expect(name.text()).toBe('foo');
  });
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: simulating is triggering? Did you try putting `console.log` inside the `handleChange`?

Comment: you need to mock useState

Comment: `handleChange` is only checking `name` and `room`. So that you always will get the default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enzyme doesn't provide proper support for react hooks.
https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/#react-hooks-support

You can use react-dom/test-utils along with enzyme. Example https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/#reacttestutilsact-wrap

But it is recommended to use [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) for better support.